# Rails 2.3.8 has_many :through

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, model-associations

I have 3 Tables/Classes

```
   vectors, b_cells and transfections
```

They are associated like this

```
    class BCell
    has_and_belongs_to_many :vectors ( JOIN ) 

    class Transfection
    has_and_belongs_to_many :vectors ( JOIN )
```

How do I connect b_cells and transfections using the associations?
I tried

```
    class BCell
    has_many :transfections, :through => :vectors

    class Transfection
    has_many :b_cells, :through => :vectors
```

I am using rails 2.3.8

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where is the problem?

Comment: Using 2.3.8 is a super bad idea. There's a lot of vulnerabilities in that version.

Comment: I am trying to get the transfections from b_cells or vice versa. Ex: if I do b_cell.mini_transfections I would need to get all the associated records

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a problem with the model declaration. Can you try this and see if it will work

```
class BCell < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vectors 
    has_many :transfections, :through => :vectors
end

class Transfection < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :vectors
    has_many :b_cells, :through => :vectors
end

class vectors < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :b_cell
    belongs_to :transfection
end
```

Comment: The tables already exist in the app I want to just add the association, there are already a lot of records so I have to use the join table so I am guessing has_many would not work in that case?

Comment: Okay I thought you are creating a new association. If you already have the table which has both the bcells and transfections does adding id to the vectors table help ?